# NSLog shows last but one log

Tags: objective-c, nslog

NSLog always shows last but one log. I've tried it in a new project as well.

```
NSLog(@"Hello 1");
NSLog(@"Hello 2");
NSLog(@"Hello 3");
NSLog(@"Hello 4");
NSLog(@"Hello 5");
NSLog(@"Hello 6");
```

Console:

```
2015-02-05 21:02:18.923 BTTest[2435:898024] Hello 1
2015-02-05 21:02:18.925 BTTest[2435:898024] Hello 2
2015-02-05 21:02:18.925 BTTest[2435:898024] Hello 3
2015-02-05 21:02:18.926 BTTest[2435:898024] Hello 4
2015-02-05 21:02:18.926 BTTest[2435:898024] Hello 5
```

If I log something after that

```
NSLog(@"Hello 7")
```

I get in console

```
2015-02-05 21:02:20.304 BTTest[2435:898024] Hello 6
```

And so on. Anyone have an idea why? Thanks

Comment: Your console print queue is not being flushed, for some reason.

Comment: (One might see this if you're running one of the kluges that supports Xcode on Windows, since Windows expects a carriage return to terminate a line.)

Comment: I have OS X Yosemite and I've also tried fflush(stderr); after NSLog, but it didn't help.

Comment: I don't think that NSLog outputs directly to stderr, but I've never really dug into it to tell for sure.